# conditional clause in Claudera

Tags: sql, cloudera-cdh

I am trying to get an if, then clause working in cloudera - along the lines:

```
    if (appointment_purpose = '') and 
appointment_purpose2 = '') and 
appointment_type2 = '') and 
appointment_type3 = '') and 
appointment_type4 = '') and 
appointment_type5 = '') and 
discuss_other ' ') then
discuss_other = 0
else discuss_other = 1,
```

How do I get this to work?
If all appointment types and appointment purposes were empty, then discuss_other should also be empty, that is 0 -  otherwise discuss_other should be 1

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN appointment_purpose = '' 
AND appointment_purpose2 = ''
AND appointment_type2 = ''
AND appointment_type3 = ''
AND appointment_type4 = ''
AND appointment_type5 = ''
AND discuss_other ' '
THEN 0
ELSE 1
) as discuss_other
FROM tableName
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, "empty" typically means `NULL`.  So, I wonder if you really intend one of these constructs:

```
select (case when appointment_purpose is null and
                  appointment_purpose2 is null and
                  appointment_type2 is null and
                  appointment_type3 is null and
                  appointment_type4 is null and
                  appointment_type5 is null and
                  discuss_other is null
             then 0 else 1
        end) as discuss_other
```

Because one of the values has a space, I wonder if you want to handle both spaces *and* null values:

```
select (case when (appointment_purpose is null or replace(appointment_purpose, ' ', '') = '') and
                  (appointment_purpose2 is null or replace(appointment_purpose2, ' ', '') = '') and
                  (appointment_purpose3 is null or replace(appointment_purpose3, ' ', '') = '') and
                  (appointment_purpose4 is null or replace(appointment_purpose4, ' ', '') = '') and
                  (appointment_purpose5 is null or replace(appointment_purpose5, ' ', '') = '') and
                  (discuss_other is null or replace(discuss_other, ' ', '') = '')
             then 0 else 1
        end) as discuss_other
```

Finally, multiple columns in the same table that are acting like an array is usually a bad sign.  Normally, this suggests that you want a junction table.

Comment: I see your point. Cloudera seems not to like replace though: Encountered: REPLACE Expected: CASE, CAST, DEFAULT, EXISTS, FALSE, IF, INTERVAL, NOT, NULL, TRUNCATE, TRUE, IDENTIFIER CAUSED BY: Exception: Syntax error